# Remove palindrome substrings in a string to create shortest string

Tags: string, algorithm, function, palindrome

How can I write a function that deletes palindromes within a string to return the shortest string possible. For example: the string “lolahal”, you could remove the largest palindromic substring (“lahal”), but you would be left with a string of length 2 (“lo”). If you remove “lol” then “aha” you would be left with the desired outcome, the string “l” that is length 1.

Comment: You can search among the alternatives, and avoid double work using dynamic programming. If you have trouble with an implementation, then ask a concrete question about that problem you have.

Comment: even a single letter is a palindrome by the standard definition, which makes your question obsolete.. please define more concretely your question and your ideas for a solution.

Comment: If deleting one palindrome creates one, can you delete that?  If so, it seems to eliminate any possible solution other than brute force search.